# Change Material color programmatically

Tags: unity, c#

I'm writing a simple C# Script to change Materials color of a object.

```
public class Highlight : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool Mouse_Over = false;
    public Color Highlight_Color = Color.white;
    private Renderer rend;
    private Material[] mats;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rend = this.GetComponentInChildren< Renderer >();
        mats = rend.materials;
    }

    public void ToggleHighlight(bool t){
        if (mats.Length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i < mats.Length; i++){
            if (t) {
                rend.materials[i].color = Highlight_Color;
            } else {
                rend.materials[i].color = mats[i].color;
            }
            Debug.Log ("Material_" + i + ".Color = " + mats[i].color.ToHexStringRGBA());
        }
    }

    void OnMouseEnter(){
        if (Mouse_Over) {
            ToggleHighlight (true);
            Debug.Log ("MouseEnter");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseExit(){
        if (Mouse_Over) {
            ToggleHighlight (false);
            Debug.Log ("MouseExit");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I store my original Materials inside the `mats` array, in the `Start` function.
This is to revert the renderer Materials to the original Materials, but it isn't working. The color doesn't change to the original value.

I tried to check where the problem was, and in the Debug statement inside the for loop, the color is getting updated also inside `mats` Array.
Why is this happening?

Seems like that `mats` is only a pointer to `rend.materials`, am I wrong?

Comment: try  mats = (Material[])rend.materials.Clone(); into the start() and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question because i have found the problem, it may be useful for someone else.

The problem is that `mats` is just a reference to `rend.Materials`, so changing values inside `rend.Materials`, also changes the values inside `mats`.

I had to create an `Array` of `Colors` to store the original Color of the materials, and then use that array to set the color when I want to revert back to the original color.

```
public class Highlight : MonoBehaviour {

public bool Mouse_Over = false;
public Color Highlight_Color = Color.white;

private Color[] oldColors;
private Renderer rend;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rend = this.GetComponentInChildren< Renderer >();
    CacheColors ();
}

private void CacheColors(){
    oldColors = new Color[rend.materials.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < oldColors.Length; i++) {
        oldColors[i] = rend.materials[i].color;
    }
}

public void ToggleHighlight(bool t){
    if (rend.materials.Length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < rend.materials.Length; i++){
        if (t) {
            rend.materials[i].color = Highlight_Color;
        } else {
            rend.materials[i].color = oldColors[i];
        }
    }
}

void OnMouseEnter(){
    if (Mouse_Over) {
        ToggleHighlight (true);
        Debug.Log ("MouseEnter");
    }
}

void OnMouseExit(){
    if (Mouse_Over) {
        ToggleHighlight (false);
        Debug.Log ("MouseExit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem myself, many of the answers were old
so will update with my solution that works

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;


public class Mat_library2 : MonoBehaviour
{
  [Header("Materials")]
  public Material[] myMaterials;
  private Material newMaterial;
  public GameObject elypseTile;
  public int RequiredColorIndex;

  public void Start()
  {
    findAllMaterials();
  }

  public void findAllMaterials()
  {
    //find all materials in resources folder Assets>Resources>Materials>
    myMaterials = Resources.LoadAll("Materials", 
    typeof(Material)).Cast<Material>().ToArray();
    Debug.Log("Materials " + 
    Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(Material)).Length);

    foreach (Material mat in myMaterials)
    {
      Debug.Log("Material is: " + mat);
      Debug.Log("RequiredColorIndex: " + RequiredColorIndex);
    }

    //Apply material from indes to game object
    elypseTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = 
    myMaterials[RequiredColorIndex].color;
  }
}
```